# Must an odd function be defined on the whole complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D\subsetℂ\to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-analytic function. I know that $f$ is an odd function on $D$. The function $f$ is the argument (angle) of an analytic function. $f$ has no known form. Be odd function is all I know about it

Is it true that $D=\mathbb{C}$, i.e., an odd function in $D$ can be extended to all of the complex plane?

Comment: Is there any reason to expect that it must be?

Comment: Since I have a function that verify this property.

Comment: What property?  You have an odd function defined on a set and that function can be extended to the whole complex plane?  [As written, your question is very confusing.  Are $f$ and $h$ supposed to be the same function?  Is $D$ supposed to be a domain or the unit disk?  By "must be defined" do you mean "can be extended?"]

Comment: @  Adam Saltz: Yes, you are right. I have edited the question.

Comment: what is your function?

Comment: The function $f$ is the argument (angle) of an analytic function. $f$ has no known form. Be odd function is all I know about it.

Comment: Still no question in here, despite @Adam's valiant tries.

Comment: @ did: I have improved the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, let 
$$F(z)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)$$
The argument of $F$ is odd on the unit disk $D$ because $F(-z)=1/F(z)$ for $z\in D$. Yet, there is no natural extension of $\arg F$ to $\mathbb C$ since  $F$ has essential singularities at $\pm 1$.